# Free spelling checker for FCKeditor?

Tags: fckeditor, spell-checking

I am looking for a free spelling checker that is compatible with FCKeditor and would work with FF & IE.
I am aware of Speller pages. Speller pages requires installing PHP and execute permissions to cmd.exe (scary?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCKeditor actually comes with a spellchecker, powered by [spellchecker.net](http://www.spellchecker.net/fcklicensed/). The version with FCKEditor is an ad-supported hosted version, but you can remove the ads for a fee. You can see it working with the FCKEditor [demo](http://www.fckeditor.net/demo), the tool launcher is on the bottom row, fourth button in from the right

There is also NetSpell, which is free and works well apparerently (I've not tried it myself). Its an [open source .NET implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell/) (you havn't specified any server language preference). There is some information on the FCK forums about NetSpell [here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=10999&hilit=netspell) and [here](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6948&hilit=netspell)